# Firebase iOS sdk error __gxx_personality_v0 not found

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm installing the Firebase Auth SDK manually, rather than using cocoapods, and I'm getting this weird error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
  +[FIRHash calculatedFingerprintForString:] in FirebaseCore(FIRHash_11b6df6535f55516149376a0824d22ab.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I installed all the resources the Auth framework depends on, so I'm not sure why this is happening. The documentation doesn't mention installing anything else. Any idea how to get this going?

Comment: Why not use Cocoapods? It makes the whole process easy and a lot less work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xcode build is not linking the C++ libraries.

Add the "-lc++" to *Other Linker Flags*

[image]